# pybrain NNregression tool parameters

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, regression, pybrain

I'm trying to use the `NNregression` tool in pybrain: http://pybrain.org/docs/api/tools.html

I have my dataset:

```
ds = SupervisedDataSet(20,1)
for x, y in zip(inputs, outputs):
    ds.appendLinked(x,y)
```

And I can get the network to train with the following initialization...

```
n = NNregression(ds)
```

...but it abruptly stops with the following error:

```
epoch   1000  total error       8.5458   avg weight          6.28
epoch   1001  total error       8.5313   avg weight        6.2823
epoch   1002  total error       8.5149   avg weight        6.2851
epoch   1003  total error       8.5003   avg weight        6.2882
epoch   1004  total error       8.4801   avg weight        6.2922
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "regression.py", line 108, in <module>
    trainer = BackpropTrainer(n, ds, verbose = True)
  File "/mounts/u-zon-d2/ugrad/kmwe236/pybrain/pybrain/supervised/trainers/backprop.py", line 37, in __init__
    self.setData(dataset)
  File "/mounts/u-zon-d2/ugrad/kmwe236/pybrain/pybrain/supervised/trainers/trainer.py", line 22, in setData
    assert dataset.indim == self.module.indim
```

So I've tried changing the parameters to include among other things validator and test sets like the documentation asks for:

```
val_data = SupervisedDataSet(20,1)
for x, y in zip(validator_inputs, validator_outputs):
    val_data.appendLinked(x,y)

test_data = SupervisedDataSet(20,1)
for x, y in zip(prediction_inputs, prediction_outputs):
    test_data.appendLinked(x,y)


n = NNregression(dataset=ds, hidden=3, TDS=test_data, VDS=val_data, epoinc=750)
```

But then when I try to execute it complains about the number of parameters:

```
violet:~/pybrain> python regression.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "regression.py", line 95, in <module>
    n = NNregression(dataset=ds, hidden=3, tds=test_data, vds=val_data, epoinc=750)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Answer (score 1):

At least for me, it did not recognize the keyword 'dataset'. Its getting 1 parameter (self), but it expects self and a dataset.Try changing the line to :

n = NNregression(ds, hidden=3, tds=test_data, vds=val_data, epoinc=750)